# MySQL Query to determine field relationship

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 fields. `principal`, `associate`, `status`.

How can I determine whether the logged-in user is either a `principal` or an `associate`, and with how many people he is associated? I would also like to determine the `status` of the relationship.

```
query = "SELECT M.id, M.surname, M.firstname, R.principal_id
         , R.associate_id, R.status 
         FROM tbl_members M, tbl_relationship R WHERE
         -- ---------------------------------------------
         -- to make sure user exists in the members table
         -- ---------------------------------------------
         (R.principal_id = M.id OR R.associate_id = M.id) 
         AND (logged-in-user = R.associate_id OR logged-in-user = R.principal_id)
         AND R.status =1"
```

ERROR:- THIS LISTS times 2 of everybody in the `relationship` table.

Tables invloved:-
tbl_members (id, surname, firstname)
tbl_relationship (id, associate_id[FK tbl_member id], principal_id[FK tbl_member id])

### associate_id | principal_id  | status

1              3              1
1              4              1
2              1              0
2              3              0
5              1              1
6              1              1

From the above how many people are associated with logged-in-user(1)?

Comment: @Tomalak I cant seem to see any changes you made.

Comment: click on "mins ago" above the editor's name and you'll see the last edits.

Comment: It would help if you could give us an example of your tables. Like the each table involved and sample data for each.

Comment: Is there now. please somebody help.

Comment: I am stuck with this table structure but would not mind an alternative so as to learn and for future use.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "how many people he is associated." Can you explain how the association works? Like a principle can have a bunch of associates (teachers perhaps) that work with him/her and the same for associates?

Comment: Exactly. How many people wants to associate with him and how many people he wants to associate with. Whoever initiates the association is the Principal and the other is the associate.

Comment: @Frank - What are the columns you want to get as a result? can you post some sample data? Do you want to get a list of all the user's associates and principals OR just a count of associates and a count of principals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
      m.id, m.surname, m.firstname,
      COUNT(assoc.id) AS relationships_as_associate, 
      COUNT(princ.id) AS relationships_as_principal
FROM tbl_members m
     LEFT JOIN tbl_relationship assoc 
          ON assoc.associate_id = m.id AND assoc.status = 1
     LEFT JOIN tbl_relationship princ 
          ON princ.principal_id = m.id AND princ.status = 1
WHERE m.id = logged-in-user
GROUP BY m.id
```

(guessing that relationships with `status = 0` can be ignored)

If you only want the number of relationships this user is in (no matter the user's role):

```
SELECT
      m.id, m.surname, m.firstname,
      COUNT(rel.id) AS active_relationships
FROM tbl_members m
     LEFT JOIN tbl_relationship rel
          ON (rel.associate_id = m.id OR rel.principal_id = m.id)
          AND rel.status = 1
WHERE m.id = logged-in-user
GROUP BY m.id
```

**EDIT:**

According to your comment, this is a query that will get all the users who are in relationship with the logged in user, with their details, and the role they are playing in the relationship (some of them are principals, others are associates):

```
SELECT m.id, m.firstname, m.surname, temp.role
FROM tbl_members m
JOIN ((SELECT rel.principal_id as id, 'Principal' as role
       FROM tbl_relationship rel
       WHERE rel.associate_id = logged-in-user
       AND rel.status = 1)
     UNION
      (SELECT rel.associate_id as id, 'Associate' as role
       FROM tbl_relationship rel
       WHERE rel.principal_id = logged-in-user
       AND rel.status = 1)
     ) as temp
ON temp.id = m.id
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but it displays details of the logged-in-user.  how can I modify it to display details(Surname and firstname) of the associates and not the logged-in-user.

Comment: @Frank - details of all of the associates?

Comment: @Frank - Forgot to add the status to the last query, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure how your system is suppose to work, but this is what I came up with.

```
Select M.id, surname, firstname, NumPrincipal, NumAssociate, 'Type' =
Case 
    When NumPrincipal > 0 Then 'Principal'
    Else 'Associate'
End

from

(Select * From tbl_members) AS M

Left Join

(Select M.id, COUNT(M.id) 'NumPrincipal' from 
tbl_members M inner join tbl_relationship R on M.id = R.principal_id
Group By M.Id) AS P

On M.id = P.id

Left Join

(Select M.id, COUNT(M.id) 'NumAssociate' from 
tbl_members M inner join tbl_relationship R on M.id = R.associate_id
Group By M.Id) AS A

On M.id = A.id

Where M.id = logged_in_user_id
```

The part that still seems weird to me is if they initiate an relationship then they will be a principal, but they can also be an associate in another case, it depends on a specific relationship between two users. My code is just if a user logs in and they have been principal before then they are a principal. Not sure if you want code that is like the current user is looking at a specific relationship they have with another user, find who is principal in that relationship?

Edit: Heres the code to see if the current user is the principal when looking at a single relationship between the current user and another user. This assumes there is only one relationship between two users or you will get multiple records back.

```
Select *,
'type' = 
case
    when principal_id = currentUserId then 'Principal' 
    else 'Associate'
end

 from tbl_relationship where
(associate_id = currentUserId  or principal_id = currentUserId ) 
and
(associate_id = OtherUserId or principal_id = OtherUserId )
```

**Edit Again, Here is the number of associates regardless of Principal/Associate:**

```
Select M.id, surname, firstname, NumAssociates 

From

tbl_members M

Left Join

(Select id, count(NumAssociate) 'NumAssociates' From 

((Select M.id, M.id 'NumAssociate' from 
tbl_members M inner join tbl_relationship R on M.id = R.principal_id where status = 1) 

Union All

(Select M.id, M.id 'NumAssociate' from 
tbl_members M inner join tbl_relationship R on M.id = R.associate_id where status = 1)) AS T

Group By Id) AS N

on M.id = N.Id
```

Comment: Please edited question for sample data. I just want how many people are associated with logged-in-user(1) irrespective of whether he is principal or associate so long as the status is 1.